# How to put positive numbers to Scanner and then stop it by entering negative one?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to put positive number to array until negative number is entered.

For example:

let the sequence of numbers introduced by the user be the following:
0 15 15 5 0 10 25 5 0 0 5 15 10 40 10 30 -2
and then the scanner must stop.
Here is what I have till now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] mas = new int[50];
    System.out.println("Type positive numbers or type negative to stop the program");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        if(n>0){
        mas[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
        else
            break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(mas[i]);
    }
}
```

But the program does not stop after enering negative number and the array is not displayed.

Comment: Give us the approach u have used till now. Then we will improve it by giving u the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. Code can be improved with exceptions checks. This one is just to get started with.

```
package com.samples;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerSample {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] mas = new int[50];

        int inputInt = scanner.nextInt();
        mas[0] = inputInt;

        int count = 1;
        while(inputInt > 0) {
            inputInt = scanner.nextInt();
            if(inputInt > 0)
                mas[count++] = inputInt;
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting now.");
        scanner.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(mas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```